# How do I move a part of a string, for every item in a list

Tags: python, list, substring

I have made a program in Python which should, for every item in the list, move a certain substring `"{Organization}"` to the end of the item.

The list: `example_list = ['Wall{Organizationmart', 'is', 'a', 'big', 'company']`

This is the code I made

```
output = []
word = '{Organization'
for i in example_list:
    output.append(i.replace(word, "") + str(word) + "}")
print(output)
```

The expected output  is: `['Wallmart{Organization}', 'is', 'a', 'big', 'company']`

However, this is the output:

```
['Wallmart{Organization}', 'is{Organization}', 'a{Organization}', 'big{Organization}', 'company{Organization}']
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: So you only want to add your word to the first item?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I only want to remove the word + add the word to the back of the word only whenever '{Organization' is in this word.

Comment: I think I found it out. I added an 'if' statement:

for i in example_list:

    if word in i:

        output.append(i.replace(word, "") + str(word) + "}")


Which only gave me as an output ['Wallmart{Organization}']


Now I also added the words that did not cointain '{Organization' to the output:


for i in example_list:

    if word in i:

        output.append(i.replace(word, "") + str(word) + "}")

    if not word in i:

        output.append(i)

Comment: You are correct, a simple if statement can fix your issue!

Comment: You just need to add a f before every string to mark it as a format tring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to check **if** organization is in each string. Slight modification to your code:

```py
output = []
word = '{Organization'
for i in example_list:
    if word in i:
        output.append(i.replace(word, "") + str(word) + "}")
    else:
        output.append(i)

print(output)
```

Output:

> ['Wallmart{Organization}', 'is', 'a', 'big', 'company']

---

Same thing with list comprehension:

```py
output = [i.replace(word, "") + str(word) + "}" if word in i else i for i in example_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

You must check if the word is in the list element and decide what to print according to that.
The solution to your problem is:

```
example_list = ['Wall{Organizationmart', 'is', 'a', 'big', 'company']

output = []
word = '{Organization'
for i in example_list:
    if word in i:
        output.append(i.replace(word, "") + str(word) + "}")
    else:
        output.append(i)
print(output)
```